# Java/Spring - Micro-services architecture, serialization between instances

Tags: java, spring, serialization, concurrency, synchronization

I am developing a micro-services architecture in Java and Spring. In this architecture, I can deploy as many instances of the same service as I want to support horizontal scalability. I am more or less following the twelve-factor philosophy (https://12factor.net).

I am in the situation that certain very specific logic can and must only be execute by exactly one instance. Does Spring (or another mature open-source project) support this? Something like:

```
@Serialized
@Scheduled(cron = "...")
public void createReports() {

}
```

Here the `@Serialized` annotation states that `createReports()` will only be executed by one instance. This could be backed by a PostgreSQL backend where a lock on a certain row is held, for example.

I could implement this myself, but I would be surprised if that would not be reinventing the wheel.

Any ideas if this is supported by Spring or another mature open-source project?

Comment: Who decides which instance is the blessed one?

Comment: What you're looking for is a distributed semaphore: It doesn't exist.

Comment: If only one instance can execute that logic, is there a point of having multiple instances for it? because at a given time only one node will be active and all the others will be idle.

Comment: To me it seems like main micro-service idea violation. At least what you  described looks like you have at least two different functionalities - one can ran on any instances, but another can run from only one. So should that second be another micro-service, instead of a part of "not micro anymore" service?

Comment: @SajithDilshan there is, for HA.

Comment: @Vadim how does separating the code solves his problem? Not to mention, there is no design principle that says that you should separate µservices based on how many instances should be executing a piece of code.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar in that case only an active and a passive node is required (otherwise resources are wasted) and the synchronized logic should be extracted out

Comment: @SajithDilshan Can we focus on the question asked? The OP didn't ask for a way to optimize resources, or for a general discussion of µservices, which there are many and wrong. If you think you need a new service for every synchronized method, then you're paid by the hour.

Comment: good luck to stuck with wrong architecture approach and try to solve initial design mistakes on low-level implementation...

Comment: Holier-than-thou, ah?

Comment: This is really a pedantic discussion :(. I could separate the logic into a separate project, but then I would face the same problem: I still would have to deploy it multiple times to achieve HA. I don't want to manually promote a node from "idle" to "master". All nodes should actively figure out who is in charge, `first come` approach is perfect. I would expect that the overhead in agreeing in such consensus is small. It's basically taking a lock in a distributed system (such as a database) and retrying every x seconds/minutes.

Comment: I found this, which looks useful and mature: https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock